# Embed R Graph in a JavaFX GUI?

Tags: java, r, networking, dynamic, visualization

I am planning on building a tool for dynamic network visualizations (more precisely I want to do science, agent-based visualization).

[image: example network visualisation]

For the visualization itself, I have found a very handy [tutorial](http://kateto.net/network-visualization) which enables me to visualize dynamic networks in R.

However, with R I can only manage to run the visualizations in my browser and believe I cannot make a standalone software with R (which eg takes an input file, enables me to build a GUI where I can select different options, print the graph ...).

I have done a few projects using Java, so my question is whether I can build my software using Java/ JavaFX and simply embed graphs that I built in R.

Comment: I don't know what "R" is and I think many others don't know either. Do you want to know how to create Graphs in JavaFX? Do you know how to parse a file that contains information about Graphs? What is your question here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package in R called rJava which allows you to integrate R Scripts in Java and the other way around. Set up your project with Maven so you can easily add the necessary dependency. I see no reason why this shouldn't work with JavaFx.

For more details watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pim3HKiWRs).